# Unable to create converter (Kotlin, Retrofit and Moshi)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I'm having an issue with a simple GET request in Retrofit.

I'm getting data from API that returns many pairs that I don't really need, so I just focused on the elements that I need to parse when it comes to this specific request.

To get an idea, this is how the response looks:

```json
[
  {
    "buildingID": 0,
    "buildingName": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "address": "string",
    "type": 0,
    "rooms": [
      {
        ...
      }
    ],
    "reservations": [
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
    ...
}
```

I'd just like to pull a few pairs out of it, so I created a following data class:

```kotlin
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class BuildingJson(@field:Json(name = "buildingID") val buildingID: Int,
                        @field:Json(name = "buildingName") val name: String,
                        @field:Json(name = "description") val description: String,
                        @field:Json(name = "address") val address: String,
                        @field:Json(name = "type") val type: Int)
```

and this is how my retrofit&moshi instance looks like (Singleton.kt):

```kotlin
object Singleton {
    val okhttp = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        })
        .build()

    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()

    const val BASE_URL = "https://localhost:5001/api/"


    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(okhttp)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(BookitAPI::class.java)
}
```

And this is how my Retrofit interface for a call looks like (wrapped in BookitAPI.kt):

```kotlin
interface BookitAPI {
    @GET("v1/BuildingApi")
    fun getBuildings(): Call<List<BuildingJson>>
}
```

This all gets called in repository with the following code:

```kotlin
 val buildingResponse = service.getBuildings().enqueue(object : Callback<List<BuildingJson>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<BuildingJson>>, t: Throwable) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<BuildingJson>>,
                response: Response<List<BuildingJson>>
            ) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")

            }
        })
```

The problem is that when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<mylab.bookitphoneapp.models.BuildingJson>
        for method BookitAPI.getBuildings
```

Does anyone have an idea how should I implement this converter that fails to be created? I've checked many resources but I still couldn't find an issue that's similar to this one.

Thanks!

Comment: **Hoping this is added to gradle file**

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

...

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.8.0'

    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.8.0'

}

Comment: I agree with @Sarah, did you add the required gradle dependency?

Comment: yayyyy, I missed the kapt dependency. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to actually annotate your data class @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)